# What is the difference between ng-include and ngroute in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm newly started from the angularJs web application using html. I want to know about the difference between ng-include and ngroute in angularjs and also when should i use of them. If anybody can know this please give me an example to learn it.

Thanks and regards,
Parthi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-include` is called a `directive` in angular, its a core concept in Angular. It lets you include `partial` html files in your page.

`ng-route` is an extra component you can add to your angular application that allows you to work with the `routing` of URL and data. In order to use it you need to reference it as a `dependency`.

```
angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"]);
```

The differences:

- one is a extension of angular with `routing` capability the other one
  is a `built-in` directive that lets you include markup on your page
  from another location.
- `ng-include` is used on the markup `<div data-ng-include="..."></div>`
- `ng-route` is used and reference in your JavaScript files.

Answer (score 3):

`ng-include` just dumps the included html into the DOM.

`ng-route` has lots of different capabilities, including route parameters.
You can see that the URL changes when you go to different routes.

Primarily routes are used for having a single page app. Different pages of the app are routed into the `ng-view`. You can then go to these pages by URL since the router will automatically resolve these routes to the right view.